# Computation of cohomology of $End(TX)$ for a ruled surface $X$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $C$ be a complex projective curve curve, let $E \longrightarrow C$ be a rank two vector bundle and let $X = \mathbb{P}(E)$ be the associated ruled surface. Then define the locally free sheaf $End(TX)$ of bundle endomorphisms of the tangent bundle $TX$.

My question is whether the cohomology groups of $End(TX)$ are already described (in terms of $E$ and $C$) in the literature. If not, how can we compute them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, 
$$
H^i(X,End(T_X)) = Ext^i(T_X,T_X).
$$
Second, there is a natural exact sequence
$$
0 \to T_{X/C} \to T_X \to p^*T_C \to 0,
$$
where $p:X \to C$ is the projection. Finally, we have relative Euler sequence
$$
0 \to O_X \to p^*E \otimes O_X(1) \to T_{X/C} \to 0,
$$
hence 
$$
T_{X/C} \cong p^*\det(E) \otimes O_X(2).
$$
Combining all this and using long exact sequences of $Ext$'s one  can compute the required cohomology groups.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Using this so far I coud prove that $h^2(End(TX)) = 3g(C)-3$,  But I'm stuck with $H^0$ and $H^1$. Any idea?

Comment: @AlanMuniz: And where precisely is your problem?

Comment: Tensorizing  $0 \to T_{X/C} \to T_X \to p^*T_C \to 0$ with other loc free sheaves it boils down to computing the cohomology of $T_{X/C}\otimes p^*T_C^\vee$ and its dual $T_{X/C}^\vee\otimes p^*T_C$.

Comment: Supposing that $e< 2g(C)-2$ and $g(C)>1$ we have $T_{X/C}\otimes p^*T_C^\vee$ ample and we can use Kodaira vanishing to its dual. Riemann-Roch completes the calculation for $T_{X/C}^\vee\otimes p^*T_C$.

Comment: However I could not figure out the cohomology of $T_{X/C}\otimes p^*T_C^\vee$.

Comment: The number $e$ above is defined by $-e$ being the minimum of self-intersection numbers of the sections.

Comment: For this you pushforward to $C$. First, $H^\bullet(X,T_{X/C} \otimes p^*T_C^\vee) = H^\bullet(C,Rp_*(T_{X/C} \otimes p^*T_C^\vee))$. Second, by projection formula $Rp_*(T_{X/C} \otimes p^*T_C^\vee) \cong Rp_*(T_{X/X}) \otimes T_C^\vee$. Finally, $Rp_*(T_{X/C}) \cong \det E \otimes S^2E^\vee$. So, it remains to compute $H^\bullet(C,\det E \otimes S^2E^\vee \otimes T_C^\vee)$. Of course, the results depends on $E$.

Comment: I just tought about that but I only don't understand why $Rp_\ast(O_X(2)) = S^2E^\vee$. Maybe it's trivial but I'm tired. How do we show that?

Comment: This is a relative version of the natural isomorphism $H^0(P(V),O(k)) = S^kV^\vee$ for $k = 2$.

Comment: Oh sure... Thanks!